# Optimize image for OCR

Tags: bitmap, xamarin.android, ocr, tesseract

I encounter some problems in developing an app that uses Tesseract. The problem is that i can`t seem to find a fast enough way to make the image good for a fast OCR scan. Can anybody point out a faster method / a library that exists that i can use to make things happen faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that Tesseract cannot be enough for you. Probably, the best way to solve your problem is your own fast OCR solution. In particular, you need to make these steps in the OCR faster: deskewing, cropping, binarization, finding connected components, symbol recognition, and text post-processing.

Usually, the longest operation in OCR is symbol recognition. I guess to make it faster you can apply GPGPU.

Before you begin with your own OCR experiments, you can get acquainted with the review of the receipt recognition research: http://rnd.azoft.com/applying-ocr-technology-receipt-recognition/
It might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use OpenCV function: adaptiveThreshold(..., CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,...). It works fast.
2. You can use better binarization algorithm (For example: SAUVOLA). But it works slowly than Mean's binarization.  See source: https://github.com/benob/opencv-utils/blob/master/include/binarize.h

Comment: 3. You can use commercial mobile OCR solutions

Comment: Can you give me an example of mobile OCR solution?